# How to calculate an area under $y=x^{-2}$ without integral

Tags: area

I need to get a formula for area under $y=x^{-2}$ for $x \in (1,a)$, where $a \in (1, +\infty)$, WITHOUT using integrals. I tried following:

1. Let $h=\frac{a}{n}$, where $n$ is natural number of sections you got by dividing abscissa from $1$ to $a$
2. Then 
   $S = h\cdot(1h)^{-2}+h\cdot (2h)^{-2}+...+h \cdot(nh)^{-2}=
   (\frac{1}{h})\cdot(1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+...+\frac{1}{n^2})=???$

What am i doing wrong? Maybe, there is another way to get this formula (without integrals)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

You have taken your lower limit wrong in your solution, If I define $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$$ $n$ be index of $n^{\text{th}}$ rectangle, and $h$ be the thickness of each rectangle, then $h = \cfrac{a-1}{n}$

Then required area would be $$A =  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a-1}{n} \sum^{n-1}_{k=0} f(1 + kh) =  (a-1) \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum^{n-1}_{k =0} \cfrac{n}{(n + k(a-1))^2} $$

Hope you can take from here, now.